# How can I make a button clicked, make other buttons !clicked in Ionic V1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div class="row rowpesquisa">
        <div class="col col-100 colpesquisatop">
        <div class="col col-25">
            <button class="button button-icon buttonsearch" ng-model="butpontoenc" ng-click="butpontoenc.clicked=!butpontoenc.clicked" ng-class="!butpontoenc.clicked?'button-tueddin':'button-tueddin'">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePontoDeEncontro@1x.svg" ng-show="!butpontoenc.clicked">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePontoDeEncontroverde.svg" ng-show="butpontoenc.clicked">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25">
            <button class="button button-icon buttonsearch" ng-model="butpessoas" ng-click="butpessoas.clicked=!butpessoas.clicked" ng-class="!butpessoas.clicked?'button-tueddin':'button-tueddin'">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePessoas@1x.svg" ng-show="!butpessoas.clicked">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePessoasverde.svg" ng-show="butpessoas.clicked">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25">
            <button class="button button-icon buttonsearch" ng-model="butpontotur" ng-click="butpontotur.clicked=!butpontotur.clicked" ng-class="!butpontotur.clicked?'button-tueddin':'button-tueddin'">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePontosTuristicos@1x.svg" ng-show="!butpontotur.clicked">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconePontosTuristicosverde.svg" ng-show="butpontotur.clicked">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25">
            <button class="button button-icon buttonsearch" ng-model="butlocais" ng-click="butlocais.clicked=!butlocais.clicked" ng-class="!butlocais.clicked?'button-tueddin':'button-tueddin'">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconeLocais@1x.svg" ng-show="!butlocais.clicked">
                <img src="img/pesquisar/iconeLocaisverde.svg" ng-show="butlocais.clicked">
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So this is my code right now. It's a search page, where 4 buttons can be clicked, like filters. But the way they work now is making the filters sum up with each other. I need to choose each filter to be shown alone. And for that, I need the of the buttons to become !clicked when any other is clicked... How can I do that?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting these to work like radio buttons?

The easy solution is to set them to false in each click so your first one would look like this:

```
ng-click="butpontoenc.clicked = true; butpessoas.clicked = false; butpontotur.clicked = false; butlocais.clicked = false;"
```

you would need to replicate this on each button or create a method on the controller that takes in the button you want to set and loops over them and sets each one accordingly.

Comment: It worked exactly how I needed, thank you very much!

I wasn't aware that I could write more than one "clicked" execution in the same button using " ; ".